# How to select last value from each run of similar items?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

I have a list. I'd like to take the last value from each run of similar elements.

What do I mean? Let me give a simple example. Given the list of words

> ['golf', 'hip', 'hop', 'hotel', 'grass', 'world', 'wee']

And the similarity function 'starting with the same letter', the function would return the shorter list

> ['golf', 'hotel', 'grass', 'wee']

Why? The original list has a 1-run of G words, a 3-run of H words, a 1-run of G words, and a 2-run of W words. The function returns the last word from each run.

How can I do this?

---

Hypothetical C# syntax (in reality I'm working with customer objects but I wanted to share something you could run and test yourself)

```
> var words = new List<string>{"golf", "hip", "hop", "hotel", "grass", "world", "wee"};
> words.LastDistinct(x => x[0])
["golf", "hotel", "grass", "wee"]
```

---

Edit: I tried `.GroupBy(x => x[0]).Select(g => g.Last())` but that gives ['grass', 
'hotel', 'wee'] which is **not** what I want. Read the example carefully.

---

Edit. Another example.

> ['apples', 'armies', 'black', 'beer', 'bastion', 'cat', 'cart', 'able', 'art', 'bark']

Here there are 5 runs (a run of A's, a run of B's, a run of C's, a *new* run of A's, a *new* run of B's). The last word from each run would be:

> ['armies', 'bastion', 'cart', 'art', 'bark']

The important thing to understand is that each run is independent. Don't mix-up the run of A's at the start with the run of A's near the end.

Comment: what is the specific output you need?

Comment: So you don't want to group only by the first letter but also on consecutive words?

Comment: I expect to see `['hotel', 'grass', 'wee']` without `golf`

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I also though so, but he really wants that golf there. It is the last word in a consecutive line of words starting with 'g' in the original sequence.

Comment: OK, can you explain why `golf` should be there? I don't see any logic here

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I was writting it, but check out new answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with

```
/// <summary>
/// Given a list, return the last value from each run of similar items.
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<T> WithoutDuplicates<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> similar)
{
    Contract.Requires(source != null);
    Contract.Requires(similar != null);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<IEnumerable<T>>().Count() <= source.Count(), "Result should be at most as long as original list");

    T last = default(T);
    bool first = true;
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (!first && !similar(item, last))
            yield return last;

        last = item;
        first = false;
    }

    if (!first)
        yield return last;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this extension that can group by adjacent/consecutive elements:

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> GroupAdjacent<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    TKey last = default(TKey);
    bool haveLast = false;
    List<TSource> list = new List<TSource>();
    foreach (TSource s in source)
    {
        TKey k = keySelector(s);
        if (haveLast)
        {
            if (!k.Equals(last))
            {
                yield return new GroupOfAdjacent<TSource, TKey>(list, last);
                list = new List<TSource>();
                list.Add(s);
                last = k;
            }
            else
            {
                list.Add(s);
                last = k;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            list.Add(s);
            last = k;
            haveLast = true;
        }
    }
    if (haveLast)
        yield return new GroupOfAdjacent<TSource, TKey>(list, last);
}

public class GroupOfAdjacent<TSource, TKey> : IEnumerable<TSource>, IGrouping<TKey, TSource>
{
    public TKey Key { get; set; }
    private List<TSource> GroupList { get; set; }
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)this).GetEnumerator();
    }
    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<TSource> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var s in GroupList)
            yield return s;
    }
    public GroupOfAdjacent(List<TSource> source, TKey key)
    {
        GroupList = source;
        Key = key;
    }
}
```

Then it's easy:

```
var words = new List<string>{"golf", "hip", "hop", "hotel", "grass", "world", "wee"};
IEnumerable<string> lastWordOfConsecutiveFirstCharGroups = words
            .GroupAdjacent(str => str[0])
            .Select(g => g.Last());
```

Output:

```
string.Join(",", lastWordOfConsecutiveFirstCharGroups); // golf,hotel,grass,wee
```

Your other sample:

```
words=new List<string>{"apples", "armies", "black", "beer", "bastion", "cat", "cart", "able", "art", "bark"};
lastWordOfConsecutiveFirstCharGroups = words
   .GroupAdjacent(str => str[0])
   .Select(g => g.Last());
```

Output:

```
string.Join(",", lastWordOfConsecutiveFirstCharGroups); // armies,bastion,cart,art,bark
```

<kbd>[**Demonstration**](http://ideone.com/NVvMxw)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing too complicated with just doing it the old-fashioned way:

```
Func<string, object> groupingFunction = s => s.Substring(0, 1);
IEnumerable<string> input = new List<string>() {"golf", "hip", "..." };

var output = new List<string>();

if (!input.Any())
{
    return output;
}

var lastItem = input.First();
var lastKey = groupingFunction(lastItem);
foreach (var currentItem in input.Skip(1))
{
    var currentKey = groupingFunction(str);
    if (!currentKey.Equals(lastKey))
    {
        output.Add(lastItem);
    }
    lastKey = currentKey;
    lastItem = currentItem;
}

output.Add(lastItem);
```

You could also turn this into a generic extension method as [Tim Schmelter has done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20241118/50079); I have already taken a couple steps to generalize the code on purpose (using `object` as the key type and `IEnumerable<T>` as the input type).

Answer (score 0):

You can use following extension method to split your sequence into groups (i.e. sub-sequnces) by some condition:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Split<T, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
{
    var group = new List<T>();

    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            yield break;
        else
        {
            TKey currentKey = keySelector(iterator.Current);
            var keyComparer = Comparer<TKey>.Default;
            group.Add(iterator.Current);

            while (iterator.MoveNext())
            {
                var key = keySelector(iterator.Current);
                if (keyComparer.Compare(currentKey, key) != 0)
                {
                    yield return group;
                    currentKey = key;
                    group = new List<T>();
                }

                group.Add(iterator.Current);
            }
        }
    }

    if (group.Any())
        yield return group;        
}
```

And getting your expected results looks like:

```
string[] words = { "golf", "hip", "hop", "hotel", "grass", "world", "wee" };

var result = words.Split(w => w[0])
                  .Select(g => g.Last());
```

Result:

```
golf
hotel
grass
wee
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this algoritm

```
        var words = new List<string> { "golf", "hip", "hop", "hotel", "grass", "world", "wee" };
        var newList = new List<string>();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < words.Count - 1 && i <= words.Count)
        {
            if (words[i][0] != words[i+1][0])
            {
                newList.Add(words[i]);
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                var j = i;
                while ( j < words.Count - 1 && words[j][0] == words[j + 1][0])
                {
                    j++;
                }
                newList.Add(words[j]);
                i = j+1;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your input is a List<>, so I think this should work for you with an acceptable performance and especially it's very concise:

```
var result = words.Where((x, i) => i == words.Count - 1 || 
                                   words[i][0] != words[i + 1][0]);
```

You can append `ToList()` on the result to get a `List<string>` if you want.